# TableView cellForRowAt indexPath method doesn't called in searchController when searchBar start typing

Tags: uitableview, swift3, tableview, uisearchbar, searchbar

I spent a lot of time in order to find a solution but I didn't found it so I ask here for help me.

I have a ViewController with a button, when I press this button the searchController appears with a searchBar, when I start to type a letter in searchBar so the tableView of the tableViewController appears above the main view and below the searchController. But there's no result appears on the cell of the tableView because the cellForRowAt indexPath method isn't called.

The following code is for the ViewController :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
var tableViewSearch: TableViewController!

lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
    let sc = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.tableViewSearch)
    sc.searchResultsUpdater = self.tableViewSearch
    sc.delegate = self
    sc.searchBar.delegate = self
    return sc
}()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableViewSearch = TableViewController()
}

@IBAction func searchWithAddress(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

The following code is the TableViewController :

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
var userTab = [String]()
var filteredUsers = [String]()
var searchController: UISearchController!
var resultsController = UITableViewController()
var name: String!
var ref: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
    self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "pseudo").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.userTab = []
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let userSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let uid = userSnap.key
                let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                let pseudo = userDict["pseudo"] as! String
                self.userTab.append(pseudo)
                self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
                continue
            }
        }
    })
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    print("updateSearchResults")
    self.filteredUsers = self.userTab.filter { (user:String) -> Bool in
        if user.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("prepare")
    if segue.identifier == "userProfil" {
        let userViewController = segue.destination as! UserViewController
        userViewController.pseudo = self.name!
    }
}

// Number of rows isn't equal to 0
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        return self.userTab.count
    } else {
        return self.filteredUsers.count
    }
}

// This method is never called
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("cellForRowAt") // This line is never printed on the console
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.userTab[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let post = filteredUsers[indexPath.row] as! String
    self.name = post
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "userProfil", sender: nil)
}
}
```

Why the cellForRowAt indexPath method isn't called? What's wrong in my code ?

Comment: `resultsController` is a arbitrary instance of `UITableViewController`. How is that instance related to the UI?

Comment: I put this line on the ViewController :  sc.searchResultsUpdater = self.tableViewSearch

Comment: Do you talk about that?

Comment: I'm talking about the line `var resultsController = UITableViewController()`

Comment: I write that on the viewDidAppear() method: tableViewSearch = TableViewController()

Comment: This is not related to UI?

Comment: Long story short: Controllers initialized with the default initializer `()` are brand new instances which are not related to the instances in the storyboard at all. You need the real references to the controllers.

Comment: Ok so how can I relate it to the controller? I don't know how to do it

Comment: Via IBOutlet, segue, protocol/delegate, callback closure or notification. The proper way depends on your design.

Comment: I can't by IBOutlet because the tableView isn't on the ViewController, I can't by segue to I think. By protocol or delegate I tried but can't work maybe I do wrong thing

Comment: The TableView is on another Swift file, but I can see the TableView displayed when I begin to type something on the searchBar, but no result wrote on the cell of tableView, so if the tableView appears it related to the UI right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157220/discussion-between-ghiggz-pikkoro-and-vadian).